# How to fix Error while install with apt-get?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Hello since yesterday i got a problem. Everytime when i try to install something on my terminal with "sudo apt-get", I run in the same Error-Message. I also checked this Error on much websites but still don't know what to do!

My Command: `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

My Error:

```
Loading new synosnap-0.10.19 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-41-generic
Building initial module for 5.13.0-41-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): krnele package linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.13.0-41-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/synosnap/0.10.19/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package synosnap (--configure):
installed synosnap package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
synosnap
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

I Hope there's a solution for this Problem!

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which version?

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades   *Your pasted kernel matches only an EOL release*

Answer (score 1):

The error is not related to `sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`.

The error is about the `synosnap` DKMS package that is incompatible with the kernel.

You can remove it by

```
sudo dkms remove synosnap/0.10.19 --all
```

Comment: So How to fix this Problem? Is there anything to do?

Comment: I added a command.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there may be an issue with the `synosnap` package that is causing problems when you try to install other packages using `apt-get`. The error message mentions that the `linux-headers-5.13.0-41-generic` package is not supported by `synosnap`.

Try removing the `synosnap` package and then trying to install the package you want again. To remove the `synosnap` package,

`sudo apt-get purge synosnap`

After running this command, you should be able to install the `pavucontrol` package

`sudo apt-get install pavucontrol`

Comment: Thank you so much it worked!

Comment: Glad to know that! you can upvote the answer then. Thanks